# Batch: Variables in for-loop do not change

Tags: batch-file, variables, for-loop

I am trying to create a batch file that does various things with all PDF-files within a directory. These are the first lines of my file:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R "C:\Daten\test" %%f IN (*.pdf) DO (
 set _currentpdf=%%f
 echo %_currentpdf%
 call %~dp0\sumatrapdf.exe %_currentpdf%
 pause
 )
```

What I do not understand is, that when running the batch the line "set _currentpdf=" is displayed correctly (i.e. the correct file for each loop-execution is displayed after =), but the value remains unchanged though and is always set to the one of the first execution of the for-loop.
Resulting in Echo and sumatrapdf always showing the first file again and again...?!

Thanks for any enlightenment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Start` command instead of the `Call` command.

I would suggest either:

```bat
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /R "C:\Daten\test" %%f In (*.pdf) Do (
    Set "_currentpdf=%%f"
    Echo !_currentpdf!
    Start "" "%~dp0sumatrapdf.exe" "!_currentpdf!"
    Pause
)
```

*You stipulated delaying expansion but didn't replace **`%`** with **`!`** in the variable you wanted to delay the expansion of*

Or you could forget about delaying expansion completely because there's no need to set any variables within the loop:

```bat
For /R "C:\Daten\test" %%f In (*.pdf) Do (
    Echo %%f
    Start "" "%~dp0sumatrapdf.exe" "%%f"
    Pause
)
```

*Also take account that your `Pause` command will lose focus between each pdf tab opening.*

Comment: What about neither using `call` nor `start`?

Comment: @aschipfl, that would completely depend upon what the OP needs, without the `Start` command SumatraPDF would need to be closed after it has opened each pdf, before it returns to the prompt for a `Pause`. Using the `Start` command will, _other than the `cmd.exe` window losing focus_, allow each `.pdf` to be opened in a new tab within the same `sumatrapdf.exe` window.

Comment: @aschipfl, Compo is right, I need the call because I want SumatraPDF to be closed before the batch continues

Comment: @Compo: Thank you very mouch, your fast answer worked. Sometimes I miss the obvious.
The reason for setting the variable is the I encapsulated several if-conditions (resulting from choice) within the loop at a later point. 
For some reason I can not explain %%f is no longer expanded at some later point in the script. Perhaps I will open another question for that if I don't get it work.
Sorry for leaving pause in the code, I added that for debugging reasons.